# Multiple accounts with the same IP address

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

There are many users who have created multiple ids with the same IP address and using them in a wrong way. Regarding this, what are the actions we should take?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given it is normal for all people working at a company to access the internet with the same IP address due to firewalls etc - and it is normal for many programmers to work at a single company, I don't think this is a good ideal.

Comment: Yup, the IP address is an unreliable heuristic at best - it was never intended to be a security measure, nor to identify the user.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are talking about the [Android chatting ban evasion](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/631026#631026). (Because you [own](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/836/android-solver) one of the many .. many Android chat rooms.)

The best way to deal with this is to flag their accounts, If there is any suspicious activity the mods will nuke those accounts.

Also if [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765959/robinhood) is trying to [impersonate you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646806/robinhood), you can always report this to the mods.

If you own both accounts, You can flag any of your posts and ask the moderator to merge these two accounts.

Comment: btw, they aren't suspended from chat.meta.so..

Comment: I guess its best to let them chat on here, because they have tried creating about 8 fake accounts to evade the suspension. They are [given a warning](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=634494#634494) by a moderator that if they misbehave on chat.meta.SO they will be suspended.

Comment: I was unaware of this, thanks for clarifying @Reno.