# How to advise a new user whose post "cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network."

Tags: discussion, new-users

This [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/attitude-determination-control-subsystem-or-on-board-computation-for-embedded-sy?noredirect=1#comment90912_30367) indicates that a new user is having difficulty posting. Apparently they've received the message:

> Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network.

I don't know how to advise them, but it's coming at the same time that they are working to improve their first question just put on hold, so it probably feels a bit unfair.

Comment: I have not used the `spam` tag because my question is how to advise the new user.

Comment: I don't think it matters much what happens to that question.  An OP with all the specs for both systems is asking internet-strangers who don't have any documentation which system would be better to learn from.  That makes no sense whatsoever:(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are good, trusted accounts really blocked too, while on a bad IP address?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251257/are-good-trusted-accounts-really-blocked-too-while-on-a-bad-ip-address)

Comment: @Rob Since the new user does not have a "good, trusted account" I don't see how that could be a duplicate. The information is interesting, and certainly related, so thank you for bringing that to attention, but the question here is about *advising a new user*.

Comment: @Rob I'm the OP here, and "direct them to the help center" is the answer to my question about "How to advise..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Direct them to [the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/abuse-block):

> It means that the abuse was extremely severe, and that we unfortunately can't accept your contribution until the abuse has subsided. Unfortunately, in most cases, this will mean that you need to contribute to the site from an alternate location until a few of your contributions have been well received by the community.

Comment: Just an idea: shouldn't that be linked from the popup which is shown to the blocked user?

Comment: Most of the people encountering that message are posting spam...

Comment: But the people smart & determined enough to know how to switch to an alternate location to spam will do that anyway ...

Comment: You'd be surprised

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed. I've never explored the help center beyond the most frequent topics I share, *I should have looked there first*, so now I'll review the whole thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> originating from your network

This more or less gives it away; they have to move *out of the network*. If they are using a fixed Internet connection, let them post from mobile (3G/4G) or vice versa. An alternative is using a proxy, VPN or Tor.

Note that editing the question should still work, even if they're being blocked from posting; that means you can post a stub from your mobile and edit it later from a laptop, if tethering is not an option for you. (But I'd advise to add a reason to your stub why you're doing it this way, lest you get downvoted.)

Note that some details of the blocking algorithm are intentionally kept secret.

Comment: FWIW, SO mod [Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [said this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258601/why-am-i-blocked-from-posting-questions-when-connected-to-a-specific-network/258603#comment37308_258603) about Tor: *"we get a lot of spam and trolling from Tor, so if you are using that anonymizing service, don't be surprised if you are blocked from posting from time to time."*